# Read the file from one Unix server to the other Unix server

Tags: file, unix, ksh, scp

I have a `Pro*C` program which I run on Unix server `say a` but the input file required for this program is on other Unix server `say b`. Whenever I run I have to copy the file from server b to a.

Is there any way that I can access the file from other server while running the program to give file name as the whole path which is on server `b`

Comment: you retagged your question. However, did you try the answers already provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can `while` loop using a file coming from the other server:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(ssh serverB 'cat /path/of/the/file')
```

By saying `ssh serverB 'command'`, the `command` is executed in `serverB`. So, saying `cat file` we have it present in our loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can NFS-mount the remote file system or make your `Pro*C` program handle the file retrieval itself (so that you can pass it the remote file location via some URL like `sftp://remote_user@server_b:/path/to/file`).